# Any idea how Linux determines which string should be printed in a kernel module?

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, arm, disassembly

Given the most basic kernel module

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>

static int __init my_mod_init(void) {
    printk("Hello World!");
    printk("Goodbye World!");
    return 0;
}
static void __exit my_mod_exit(void) { }

module_init(my_mod_init);
module_exit(my_mod_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

GCC generates the following armv7 assembly (objdump)

```
dummy.ko:     file format elf32-littlearm

Disassembly of section .init.text:

00000000 <init_module>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   e3000000    movw    r0, #0
   8:   e3400000    movt    r0, #0
   c:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <printk>
  10:   e3000000    movw    r0, #0
  14:   e3400000    movt    r0, #0
  18:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <printk>
  1c:   e3a00000    mov r0, #0
  20:   e8bd8010    pop {r4, pc}

Disassembly of section .exit.text:

00000000 <cleanup_module>:
   0:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

The rodata section looks like this:

```
Contents of section .rodata.str1.4:
 0000 48656c6c 6f20576f 726c6421 00000000  Hello World!....
 0010 476f6f64 62796520 576f726c 642100    Goodbye World!.
```

I at least expected `r0` at lines 0x10 and 0x14 to be something like `mov r0, #16` or `ldr r0, [pc, #12]`. How is the second `printk` function informed to print *"Goodbye World!"*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `.ko` is apparently like a `.o` - a relocatable object file, not an ELF executable or shared object.

So there are just placeholders in the machine code, with the actual address only filled in at load time based on relocation info.

**Disassemble with `objdump -dr` to show relocations with symbol names.  (Or `objdump -drWC`)**, same as when you're disassembling a `.o`.

Comment: `objdump -dr` is exactly what I needed! I completely forgot .so and .ko contained relocatable content; nor did I realize the `-d` option didn't take relocation into account.

Comment: @TekuConcept: Just for the record, for `.so` dynamic relocations you want `-R`